# How would I write a terminal command to download a folder with wget from a Media Temple (gs) server?

Tags: ftp, authentication, connection, wget, mediatemple

I'm trying to download a folder using wget on the Terminal (I'm usin a Mac if that matters) because my ftp client sucks and keeps timing out. It doesn't stay connected for long. So I was wondering if I could use wget to connect via ftp protocol to the server to download the directory in question. I have searched around in the internet for this and have attempted to write the command but it keeps failing. So assuming the following:

ftp username is: serveradmin@mydomain.ca
ftp host is:     ftp.s12345.gridserver.com
ftp password is:     somepassword

I have tried to write the command in the following ways:

```
wget -r ftp://serveradmin@mydomain.ca:somepassword@s12345.gridserver.com/path/to/desired/folder/

wget -r ftp://serveradmin:somepassword@s12345.gridserver.com/path/to/desired/folder/
```

When I try the first way I get this error:

```
 Bad port number.
```

When I try the second way I get a little further but I get this error:

```
Resolving s12345.gridserver.com... 71.46.226.79
Connecting to s12345.gridserver.com|71.46.226.79|:21... connected.
Logging in as serveradmin ... 
Login incorrect.
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you are running a `wget` command, but can not issue `wget -h`? :)

```
FTP options:
       --ftp-user=USER         set ftp user to USER.
       --ftp-password=PASS     set ftp password to PASS.
```

So your command becomes

`wget -r --ftp-user="serveradmin@mydomain.ca" --ftp-password=somepassword ftp://s12345.gridserver.com/path/to/desired/folder/`

You most likely will have to put " " around the username because it contains `@` character

Comment: It totally worked. Thank you so much. I've been racking my head for a couple of hours trying to get this exact command to work. I asked this same question at Stackoverflow & someone suggested that I could use the scp instead & it works on Media Temple because I have ssh access but I feared it wouldn't work on other hosting services without ssh access.

Final question: what flag could I put so that it doesn't download every folder in between? E.g. suppose the path to the folder is this: /domains/mydomain/html/webdir and I just want webdir/ to be downloaded and not domains/, mydomain/ and html/?

Comment: Glad i could help! To avoid downloading "parent" folders, use `-np` (same as `--no-parent`) option. It should do what you need.

Comment: +1 for "So you are running a wget command, but can not issue wget -h?".

Comment: I did look at the command line options but I guess I had no patience to try too many configurations before getting frustrated. I'd rather ask questions first to get an idea.